# App crashes after take photo in iOS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I'm developing my app with "Adobe Flash CC 2014" with AIR 15 SDK.
I tested with iPhone 5S while developing. On iPhone 5S everything works perfect.
Today i try to test with iPhone 4 and it crashing while after taking photo with camera.
I didn't use ANE file for taking photo. I google it this issue, someones write this is memory issue.
Any ideas for what am i going to do?

**edit:**
I used distriqt Camera ane to solve this issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off topic: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"